# Set Cell value in jtable based on entry made in another cell using keyreleased event

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a `jtable` that is linked to a mysql table.

The table has two columns '`Item_no`' and '`Item_description`'

**What I want is:** Once a user completes typing the `item_no` in the `jtable`, the adjacent cell(Item Description) is filled with the corresponding description from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Override `setValueAt` of the `TableModel`. When the item number column value is set, load the corresponding value from the database and update the model accordingly.

See [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, what keyevent should I code for when overriding setValueAt, keypressed, keyreleased or keytyped?

Comment: You shouldn't. The method will be called once the editor is "stopped" and the value is to be committed to the model

Comment: I finally cracked it. After days of trial and error. The trick is to add CellEditorListener, override method editingStopped and loop through the jtable rows and using setValueAt. Finally  fireTableCellUpdated

Comment: @user3424987 That  is not a solution, as this is essentially what JTable does. If you find you're self having to do this, then something else is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!
AllocationsTable.getCellEditor(0,0).addCellEditorListener(new CellEditorListener() {

```
               @Override
               public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent ce) {
                   PreparedStatement ps;
    String sql = "Select * from items where item_no= ?";
    try
    {
        for (i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i++)
        {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
        ResultSet rst;
        rst = ps.executeQuery();
        rst.last();
        model.setValueAt(rst.getString("Description"), i, 1);
        model.fireTableCellUpdated(i, 1);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: This is the responsibility of the model, when setValueAt is called, you should simply look up the row that is changed and update the cell, firing a tableCellUodated event for both cells. No one should be calling fireTable events expect the model itself